# Performing a left outer join when an nhibernate filter is applied

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to perform a LEFT OUTER JOIN with nhibernate criteria. I also have a filter that gets applied to my queries.

The problem I have is the filter stops the left outer join working properly if the join result is null.

As a very simple example I want to return all the musicians, and if they are in a band then also their band

NHibernate generates the following sql

```
SELECT this_.Name, band2_.Name
FROM   Musicians this_
       left outer join [Band] band2_
         on this_.BandID = band2_.ID
WHERE  (band2_.IsDeleted = 0)
```

which won't return the musicians if they aren't in a band. What I want is something like

```
SELECT this_.Name, band2_.Name
FROM   Musicians this_
       left outer join [Band] band2_
         on this_.BandID = band2_.ID
WHERE  this_.ID = 4894 /* @p3 */
       (band2_.ID IS NULL OR band2_.IsDeleted = 0)
```

Is this possible with nhibernate?

*UPDATE*

```
var projections = new[]
                {
                    Projections.Property("Musician.Name").As("MusicianName"),
                    Projections.Property("Band.Name").As("BandName")
                };

            return this.sessionProvider.GetSession().CreateCriteria<Musician>("Musician")
                .CreateCriteria("Musician.Band", "Band", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                .SetProjection(projections)
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Musician.ID", parameters.MusicianId))
                .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<MusicianDetailsResult>())
                .UniqueResult<MusicianDetailsResult>();
```

The filter is defined with FluentNHibernate

```
this.WithName(FilterName).WithCondition("IsDeleted = 0")
```

Comment: Can you post the ICriteria code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug in NHibernate](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1930).

I used proposed workaround and set `useManyToOne` on the filter to false. This property isn't currently in FluentNhibernate so I just do it in `ExposeConfiguration`

```
foreach (var key in cfg.FilterDefinitions.Keys)
{
  filter = cfg.FilterDefinitions[key];
  cfg.FilterDefinitions[key] = new  FilterDefinition(
    filter.FilterName,
    filter.DefaultFilterCondition, 
    filter.ParameterTypes, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is much easier if you simply map Band to Musician as a reference:

```
public class MusicianDbMap : ClassMap<Musician>
{
    public MusicianDbMap()
    {
         ...
         References(x => x.Band)
             .Nullable()
             .Not.LazyLoad(); // Or lazy load... either way
    }
}
```

Then you can just run a simple query - here it is in Linq-2-NHibernate:

```
 Session.Linq<Musician>()
      .Where(x => x.Band == null || !x.Band.IsDeleted)
      .ToList();
```

Secondly, I'm not sure about this statement of yours: "which won't return the musicians if they aren't in a band"... I'm not sure if that is correct. A left outer join should return all rows, regardless of whether they are in a band or not - are you sure that you haven't made an error somewhere else?

Comment: Musician is mapped to Band as a reference.

If you look at the sql that nhibernate generates, the filter that gets applied (band2_.IsDeleted = 0) stops the musicians without bands being returned (despite the left join). if you add the IS NULL check then it works as I want.